# In SSMS, the rows get affected but there is no output when using CTE along with table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

***Table Details :***

Class_1 (Id int,Name nvarchar(50),Address nvarchar(50))
Class_2 (Id int,Name nvarchar(50),Address nvarchar(50))

Note: There are 3-row entries in each table

***Code:***

```sql
DECLARE @StudentDetails TABLE
(
   Id int,
   Name nvarchar(50),
   Address nvarchar(50)
)

;with CTE_StudentInformation as
(
    Select Id,Name,Address from Class_1
    union all
    Select Id,Name,Address from Class_2
)

insert into @StudentDetails (Id,Name,Address)
Select Id,Name,Address from CTE_StudentInformation
```

```
Output :- 6 rows affected
```

Expected :- All the Details from 2 tables in table format

Comment: What do you mean "All the Details from 2 tables in table format"? Doesn't  @StudentDetails contain the six rows you have in Class_1 table plus Class_2?

Comment: I mean, I want to see all the data that is present in @StudentDetails table in table format, not just the rows affected. Ps : I am newbie in SQL server. I wanted to know, whether it is possible to get data like below:   
2 Mayuresh  W
3 Shantanu   C
1 Balaji   T
2 Anushri   M
3 Ashutosh   D

Comment: Then, as @KeithMiller already answered, you are missing the SELECT on your table.

Comment: Why would you expect a result set from an `INSERT`? An `INSERT` *inserts* data, it doesn't return it. You either need to `SELECT` from the table variable `@StudentDetails ` after your `INSERT` or use an `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: Ok I got it, Thank you so much @KeithMiller. I missed the Select statement that should have been executed along with the above code.

Comment: Why do you need a table variable anyway, why not just `SELECT Id... UNION ALL SELECT ...`

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, actually I am learning SQL server and I came through this scenario. That's it !!

Answer (score -1):

Is that all of your code?  I would expect that you have to select the rows out of the @StudentDetails table before you can see them if that is what you are looking for.  'Select * from @StudentDetails' as a new statement after the insert should do it for you